# Why doesn't NASM initialize the register's value properly?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm

I wanna make a driver that prints a string on the screen without BIOS (in Protected Mode). I'm using QEMU (using qemu-system-x64_86) and NASM.

I'm trying to move 0xb8000 address into ebx, but something goes wrong, here's the code of the second bootloader's stage, where I'm trying to switch to PM and call my driver function:

```
bits 16
org 0x7e00

jmp main

%include "./lib/gdt.inc"
%include "./lib/driver_print_string.asm"    ; THE function


main:
    cli                       ; disable interrupts
    xor ax, ax                ; null segments
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x07c0            ; the stack is under 0x7c00
    sti                       ; enable interrupts

call installGDT           ; installing GDT!!!

; ENTERING PM MODE!
cli
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x8:final_stage


; =============================================================
; FINAL STAGE!
bits 32

final_stage:
    cli

    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov esp, 0x07c0

dr_calling:
    mov esi, sty

    call print_string_esi


jmp $


sty: db "The driver is working!", 0

times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

gdt.inc:

```
bits 16

installGDT:
    cli
    pusha
    lgdt [toc]
    sti
    popa
    ret

;*******************************************
; Global Descriptor Table (GDT)
;*******************************************

gdt_data:
    dd 0                ; null descriptor
    dd 0

; gdt code:             ; code descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b            ; access
    db 11001111b            ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

; gdt data:             ; data descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b            ; access
    db 11001111b            ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

end_of_gdt:
toc:
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_data - 1    ; limit (Size of GDT)
    dd gdt_data             ; base of GDT
```

And driver_print_string.asm:

```
print_string_esi:
    mov ebx, 0xb8000

    mov byte [ebx], 'x'
    mov byte [ebx+1], 0x7       

    jmp $
```

But nothing works. If I wrote "info registers" in QEMU command line, it shows me that EBX=00008000, but why it isn't b8000? If I executed this changed dr_calling function:

```
dr_calling:
    mov esi, sty
    mov ebx, 0xb8000

    mov byte [ebx], 'x'
    mov byte [ebx+1], 0x7

    jmp $
```

everything works and QEMU shows that EBX=000b8000. How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect that print_string_esi is assembled as 16 bit code but executed in 32 bit mode. If so, the assembler would insert an operand size prefix (to access ebx in 16 bit mode), but when executed in 32 bit mode causes it to be executed as a 16 bit instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because driver_print_string.asm is included after `bits 16` at the beginning, so it will be compiled as 16 bit code with 32 bit addressing. but you call it from 32 bit code below. if you inline it, it is compiled as 32 bit code. just include this function somewhere below `bits 32`